# Using TLS 1.1/1.2 in WSO2 ESB out-going request

Tags: web-services, ssl, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I'm trying to consume a web service over HTTPS using WSO2 ESB (4.7.0). The web service requires all callers to use a TLS version >1.0 (1.1 or 1.2).

I'm using Java 1.7.

I've added the following line to my PassthroughTransportSender (and Receiver) definition to no avail:

```
<parameter name="HttpsProtocols">TLSv1.2</parameter>
```

How can I make WSO2 Callout and Send mediators use newer TLS versions (preferably TLS 1.2)?

Comment: Do you solved this problem? I meet this error, and set `HttpsProtocols`, ESB 4.8.0 still use the TLSv1. BTW, i also use the proxy in sender.

Comment: @James, Unfortunately I was unable to solve the problems using any of the approaches proposed in the answers using WSO2 ESB 4.7.0.

What we ended up doing with my team, was set up a proxy that knows TLS 1.2 and routed the ESB's HTTPS traffic through the proxy. I know this approach is suboptimal, but it's the best we were able to come up with without updating our ESB to a newer version, which would have included quite a few configuration changes (a project of its own). For this to work you need to install the proxy's SSL certificate in the ESB's keystore.

Comment: yeah. Thx. Get your idea. But i ask my back end services enable TLSv1 back. Anyway, our team already decided moving to dropwizard. Only need maintain the ESB services.

Answer (score 0):

Open the axis2.xml file resides under the $ESB_HOME/repository/conf/axis2 directory. Add the

```
<parameter name="HttpsProtocols">TLSv1</parameter>
```

entry inside the PassThroughHttpSSLListener and PassThroughHttpSSLSender elements.

Note that if you are using an older version of the ESB which does NOT support Passthrough transport you may need to add the above tag inside the HttpCoreNIOSSLListener and HttpCoreNIOSSLSender elements.You may get some more information in my blog post [1]

[1] http://ravindraranwala.blogspot.com/2014/11/ssl-debugging-in-wso2-esb.html

Comment: TLS 1.0 is exactly what I MUST NOT USE. I need to use a minimum of TLS 1.1.

Comment: This is just a reference answer. So change it according to your requirement.

Comment: I've updated the question with a configuration snippet I tried using long before writing this question. In short, it doesn't work.

Comment: Try it with WSo2 ESB 4.9.0. It will work. As far as I know this works with ESB 4.8.1 as well. Just give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Updating the ESB was out of the question at the time. That's why the required ESB version was specifically mentioned in the very beginning of the question. Updating a WSO2 ESB running multiple complex proxy services, API's and other synapse resources is far from trivial, as I'm sure you are well aware. Extensive changes in the configuration would be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with ESB 4.9.0 & jdk 1.8.

Add the below parameter to the PassThroughHttpSSLSender as below.

```
<transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
    .....
    <parameter name="HttpsProtocols">TLSv1.2</parameter>
    .....
</transportSender>
```

Then an outbound connection use TLSv1.2.

Comment: This approach does not work with the required ESB version of 4.7.0.